# Paper Size and Margins in PS/PDF

Tags: pdf, margins, paper-size

Actually, I am trying to submit some paper to NSERC (Canada's research fund) and they are asking:

- paper size = 8.5 x 11
- margins (all sides) = 0.75in

I tried to use the following code in LaTeX

```
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,margin=0.75in]{geometry}
```

but when I submit it, it says that I am using a wrong paper format (8.3 x 11.7). I do not understand where does the problem come from. Is it a problem with latex, dvips, ps2pdf ... ?

A MWE would be

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,margin=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
%\begingroup
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\section*{Energy harvesting-fueled D2D cooperative networks: Performance Analysis, Resource Optimization and Stochastic Geometry Modeling}
Spectrum scarcity, energy limitation for wireless devices and network complexity are among the big challenges facing research with the \ac{5G} technologies and standards. As the \ac{RF} spectrum is regulated by governmental bodies, static frequencies allocation has lead to the underutilization of the spectrum. In previous years, \ac{CR} has been proposed  as an alternative to overcome this problem: it allows non-authorized terminals or \acp{SU} to access the media as long as they respect some constrains to the interference created at \acp{PU} and the \acp{PU} activities.  While this alternative technology has driven a lot of research, the wireless devices need to permanently monitor the spectrum to detect the presence or absence of \acp{PU} which lower the power level at the wireless terminals. While energy harvesting has already been used in other fields (such as solar), it appears to be an excellent choice for wireless devices. With \ac{RF} energy harvesting, mobile users can run their terminal/device longer while having smooth communication. Nevertheless, the \ac{RF} harvesting energy reduces the useful data rate as it needs a fraction of the transmission time to collect the energy.

As a system model, we consider a \ac{D2D} communication where a source terminal $S$ tries to send information to a destination node $D$. Under the specification of the \ac{LTE}-Advance standard, the two nodes can bypass the \ac{BS} and communicate directly. In any signal-degrading scenario, a cooperative communication is considered, either with the help of the \ac{BS} or another intermediate terminal. We consider that the system uses \ac{TDMA}. This means that during a cooperative scenario, more than one \ac{TS} is necessary for an end-to-end communication.

The main objectives of the project are to be carried out by considering a statistical approach based on stochastic geometry to model and evaluate the performance of the proposed system. Stochastic geometry provides mathematical models for defining and computing macroscopic properties of classical channels of multiuser information theory. They are obtained by some averaging over all node patterns found in a large random network of the Euclidean plane. One of the most important geometric objects are the coverage regions of a transmitter or a set of transmitters.

The main objectives of the project are listed hereafter:
\vspace{-0.1in}
\begin{enumerate} 
    \itemsep-0.2em 
    \item Studying the performance of the system/network by deriving the \ac{SINR} of the end-to-end communication. The \ac{SINR} remains a fundamental metric that allows the derivation of closed-form expressions for other characterizing metrics such the ergodic and/or the effective capacity, the outage probability and the \ac{ABER}. These derivations are a continuity of my PhD works where I studied the performance analysis of cooperative systems in \ac{SS} environments, but without considering the interference.
    \item Providing robust algorithms for the detection and harvest of the \ac{RF} signals and optimizing the duration of the \acp{TS} by taking into consideration a balanced ratio between the time allocated for energy harvesting and data transmission.
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have a default `a4 paper` setting. Revert this to `letter`, or change the `\pdf...` settings. See the linked answer on how to do this.

Comment: @Werner shouldn't that be dealt with by the `geometry` package the OP is already using? I'd also test the PDF produced by `pdflatex` instead of the `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` route as there are more things to go wrong. I've tested both and in both cases Adobe Reader ended up giving the same (correct) size for the PDF.

Comment: I tried to use PdfLatex instead of the chain latex-ps-pdf and it worked. I would say it is fine for the moment.